# Prolog: Find Minimum again and again until the list is empty

Tags: prolog

How can I repeatedly extract minimum number until the list is empty?

I want to find a minimum number, then exclude it from the original list, then find a minimum again and again, until the list becomes empty.

Input:

```
?- Find_Minimum([2, 1, 4, 3, 5], C)
```

Output:

```
C = 1
C = 2
C = 3
C = 4
C = 5
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple solution using `sort/2` (in SWI):

```
minimum(L,E):-
    sort(L,LSorted),
    pick(LSorted,E).
pick([H|_],H).
pick([_|T],E):-
    pick(T,E).

?- minimum([2,1,4,3,5],E).
E = 1
E = 2
E = 3
E = 4
E = 5
false
```

Keep in mind that `sort/2` removes duplicates. If you want to keep them use for instance `msort/2` (in SWI). For an even simpler solution you can use `member/2`:

```
minimum(L,E):-
    sort(L,LSorted),
    member(E,LSorted).

?- minimum([2,1,4,3,5],E).
E = 1
E = 2
E = 3
E = 4
E = 5
```

Comment: There is no point in doing so... Just if he does not want to use member/2...

Answer (score 0):

I would had written - more or less - the same answer as @damianodamiano (+1), but tried nevertheless to code something more 'direct' than sorting. It turns out the outcome is rather technical...

```erlang
:- module(minext, [minext/2,minext/3]).

minext(L,M) :-
    minext(L,T,R),
    (   M=T
    ;   minext(R,M)
    ).

minext(L,X,R) :-
    select(X,L,R),
    \+((
        member(Y,R),
        Y<X
    )), !.
```